# How do I connect to IBM Db2 Event Store from MATLAB?

Tags: java, matlab, jdbc, db2, ibm-event-store

Is it possible to connect to an IBM Db2 Event Store instance from MATLAB ?

Comment: Is there a question here?  If this is a self-answered question, you should put the answer in an answer, not in the question itself

Comment: Hi @PaulVernon tried, but does not let me yet, I will edit it to split it as a question and answer once it allows me. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulVernon finally got to reworking the Q&A

Answer (score 0):

IBM Db2 Event Store 2.0 supports the standard Db2 JDBC driver as it is integrated with the IBM Common SQL engine. Then to connect to MATLAB using the Database Explorer I just used the standard Db2 JDBC connection using the Db2 JDBC driver:

1. Make sure you have the Database toolbox that provides the Database Explorer in MATLAB
2. First go to the MATLAB editor and type: edit javaclasspath.txt in the Command Window, and in that file add the file path to the Db2 JDBC client driver downloaded from the[IBM Data Server Client Packages page under the IBM Support website](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217):

- E.g. `/<path where the JDBC jar was placed>/db2jcc4.jar`

3. (AFTER UPDATING javaclasspath.txt restart MATLAB or [look at this for reference](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103763-why-does-the-contents-of-javaclasspath-txt-not-get-added-to-the-static-class-path-when-i-double-clic))
4. Go to the Apps tab in MATLAB app and select Database Explorer
5. Select Configure Data Source and select "Configure JDBC Data Source" from the drop down menu
6. Download the SSL keystore and password through the REST API using the instructions documented in the [IBM Knowledge Center for Event Store](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGNPV_2.0.0/develop/rest-api.html), this is necessary because IBM Db2 Event Store is configured with SSL with a a default keystore out of the box (this may change if you configure it your own keystore after installation).
7. In the JDBC Data Source Configuration Editor window do the following:

- Enter any new name for the data source, e.g. `EventStoreJDBC`
- Enter `OTHER` as the vendor
- For Driver enter: `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`
- In URL, add in the following: `jdbc:db2://<Your Event Store Cluster VIP>:18729/EVENTDB:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=<path to clientkeystore downloaded from cluster>;sslKeyStoreLocation=<path to clientkeystore downloaded from cluster>;sslKeyStorePassword=<password for clientkeystore retrieved from cluster>;sslTrustStorePassword=<password for clientkeystore retrieved from cluster>;securityMechanism=15;pluginName=IBMIAMAuth;`
- Then click on any part of the window and the TEST button will pop up
- Select TEST and you will be asked for a userid and password, where you can enter the eventstore userid and password for your system (e.g. `admin` and `password`)
- Then you close the window.

Note these same instructions can be found in the [IoT sample use case github repository for IBM Db2 Event Store](https://github.com/IBMProjectEventStore/db2eventstore-IoT-Analytics/tree/master/AdvancedApplications/JDBCApplication)

How do I do the same using the database object ?

This is what I tried

```
conn = database('db2inst1','admin','password','com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver','jdbc:db2://<Your Event Store Cluster VIP>:18729/EVENTDB:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=<path to clientkeystore downloaded from cluster>;sslKeyStoreLocation=<path to clientkeystore downloaded from cluster>;sslKeyStorePassword=<password for clientkeystore retrieved from cluster>;sslTrustStorePassword=<password for clientkeystore retrieved from cluster>;securityMechanism=15;pluginName=IBMIAMAuth;');
```

This is what I see

```
>> conn = database('db2inst1','admin','password','com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver','jdbc:db2://9.30.192.111:18729/EVENTDB:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=/Users/cmgarcia/Documents/MATLAB/eventstore/clientkeystore;sslKeyStoreLocation=/Users/cmgarcia/Documents/MATLAB/eventstore/clientkeystore;sslKeyStorePassword=Cc2cZ8TxdhWf;sslTrustStorePassword=Cc2cZ8TxdhWf;securityMechanism=15;pluginName=IBMIAMAuth;')

conn = 

  connection with properties:

                  DataSource: 'db2inst1'
                    UserName: 'admin'
                      Driver: 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'
                         URL: 'jdbc:db2://9.30.192.111:1 ...'
                     Message: ''
                        Type: 'JDBC Connection Object'
  Database Properties:

                  AutoCommit: 'on'
                    ReadOnly: 'off'
                LoginTimeout: 0
      MaxDatabaseConnections: 0

  Catalog and Schema Information:

              DefaultCatalog: ''
                    Catalogs: {''}
                     Schemas: {'ADMIN', 'NULLID', 'NULLIDR1' ... and 12 more}

  Database and Driver Information:

         DatabaseProductName: 'DB2/LINUXX8664'
      DatabaseProductVersion: 'SQL110190'
                  DriverName: 'IBM Data Server Driver fo ...'
               DriverVersion: '4.26.14'

>>
```